# How to Restrict WordPress 3 Blog Posts to Admin Only?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a WordPress blog where users can contribute articles and wiki entries (http://webypedia.com). The blog posts are normal post types. The articles and wiki entries are custom post types. I would like contributors to be able to add new articles and wiki entries, but leave the creation of new blog posts to Admin.

How do I create this kind of restriction?

Currently, out of the box, the contributor can create new post, article, and wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change [the capabilities of a role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), with your own code or with [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/). Remember to change the `capability_type` of your custom post types, otherwise you can't make a difference between a regular and a custom post.